# Android LiveData: Not receiving all notifications

Tags: android, frequency, observer-pattern, android-livedata

I'm experimenting with Android's [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata). I just tried to push a lot of notifications to an observer that observes a LiveData object. I let a thread run in background and in a while-loop i constantly push random values via LiveData's postValue-method. The number of received notifications (number of onChanged()-callbacks) in the observer which observes the livedata is much less then the number of calls of postValue in the background thread.

Can somebody explain what's the reason for this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: i tried different sleep-intervals between the posts. as i am trying to check how my app reacts to a lot of data, i let the thead sleep for a nanosecond in between

Comment: did you get the solution to your problem? I having a similar issue.

Comment: No. I tried to perform a stress test in which i maximized the number of push notifications. Turned out the mechanism of the LiveData class increased the robustness of my program, so i did not try to change the behaviour of the LiveData class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The explanation lies in the implementation for `postValue` and `mPostValueRunnable`:

```
protected void postValue(T value) {
    boolean postTask;
    synchronized (mDataLock) {
        //this is true on the first run or right after the observer receives an update
        postTask = mPendingData == NOT_SET;
        mPendingData = value;
    }
    // this statement will be true if the observer hasn't received an update even though it's sent to the main looper
    if (!postTask) { 
        return;
    }
    ArchTaskExecutor.getInstance().postToMainThread(mPostValueRunnable);
}

private final Runnable mPostValueRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Object newValue;
        synchronized (mDataLock) {
            newValue = mPendingData;
            mPendingData = NOT_SET;//once this value is reset a new mPostValueRunnable can be sent
        }
        // here the observer will receive the update
        setValue((T) newValue);
    }
};
```

1. On the first run, in `postValue` `mPendingData = NOT_SET` so the following `if (!postTask)` condition is `false` and thus `mPostValueRunnable` is sent to the main thread.
2. On the second run, if the `mPostValueRunnable` hasn't been executed yet (it may not as values are updated extremely frequently), the `if` is `true` and so nothing is sent to the main thread except that `mPendingData` is set to a new value.
3. On the third run, it can be the same as on the previous one and so on for some number of updates. Thereof, until `mPostValueRunnable` actually runs and resets `mPendingData` to `NOT_SET`, all the update values are lost except for the last one. In this case, only one update comes via `Observer` with the latest value.